# How to loop through a dataframe column name with conditions in Python Pandas to get min value?

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, conditional-statements

I would like to learn how to loop through a columns name with conditions in pandas.
For example, I have a list T = [400,500,600]. I have dataframe with columns name are G_ads_400, G_ads_500 ...
I would like to get the min value of the G_ads_ columns if T's value match G_ads_... using for-loop and if-statement (I am only familiar with these 2. Open for other suggestion)
For example: Take min value of G_ads_400 when T = 400
here is my code

```
T = [400,500,600,700]
for t in T:
    if t in df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('t')]:
         min_value = df.columns.min()
print(min_value)
```

I tried few other ways but it didnt work. It was either return error or only the name of the columns. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do it easily like this.This will return all min values for column matches with T values.

```
T = [400,500,600,700]
columns = [f"G_ads_{i}" for i in T]
res=df[columns].min()
```

if you need a min values as a dataframe

```
res=df[columns].min().to_frame().T
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help!! I have been searching for help for a while and could not find any answer.